# Java Comparable inheritance

Tags: java, comparable

I have a base **BusinessObject** abstract class which implements Comparable by comparing their **long id** fields. Now imagine I extend it with, say, **Person** and then I extend Person with **Worker**. So we have:

BusinessObject < Person < Worker

So now I override the compareTo(BusinessObject) in business object in Person (compare the names) and Worker (compares the job name, then person name).

Now I do something like:

```
List<BusinessObject> collection = new ArrayList<>();
collection.add(new Worker(1L, "Steve", "janitor"));
collection.add(new Worker(2L, "Mark", "plumber"));
collection.add(new Person(3L, "Dave"));

Collections.sort(collection);
System.out.println(collection);
```

By logging I can see the calls that are made:

1. Worker.compareTo()
2. Person.compareTo()

So, it means sorting methods are mixed which is obviously not good. So what is the correct way to implement Comparable with inheritance so that the method called depends on the generic type of the collection:

1. if collection is a List then always use BusinessObject.compareTo()
2. if collection is a List then always use Person.compareTo()
3. if collection is a List then always use Worker.compareTo()

Here's my code:

```
public abstract class BusinessObject implements HasId, HasText, Comparable<BusinessObject> {
    protected @Nullable Long id;

    public BusinessObject(@Nullable Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public @Nullable Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(@NonNull BusinessObject o) {
        System.out.println("compareTo BusinessObject");
        return Long.compare(id, o.id);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("BusinessObject#%d", id);
    }
}

public class Person extends BusinessObject {
    protected final String name;

    public Person(@Nullable Long id, String name) {
        super(id);
        this.name = name;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String getText(Context context) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Person#%d (%s)", id, name);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(@NonNull BusinessObject o) {
        if (o instanceof Person) {
            System.out.println("compareTo Person");
            Person po = (Person) o;
            return name.compareTo(po.name);
        }
        else {
            return super.compareTo(o);
        }
    }
}

public class Worker extends Person {
    protected final String job;

    public Worker(@Nullable Long id, String name, String job) {
        super(id, name);
        this.job = job;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Worker#%d (%s-%s)", id, name, job);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(@NonNull BusinessObject o) {
        if (o instanceof Worker) {
            System.out.println("compareTo Worker");
            Worker wo = (Worker) o;
            return String.format("%s%s", name, job).compareTo(String.format("%s%s", wo.name, wo.job));
        }
        else {
            return super.compareTo(o);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please paste your Person and Worker code

Comment: The obvious way is not to mix two different types of objects in a single list. If you mix them, you are bound to get these kind of results as you are comparing apples and apple juice.

Comment: Please clarify "if collection is a List then always use BusinessObject.compareTo()
if collection is a List then always use Person.compareTo()
if collection is a List then always use Worker.compareTo()".

Comment: If you're implementing `Comparable` you do not have any information about the other elements of the list (except the elements to get compared with). So you cannot differ which comparison to use

Comment: @solomkinmv Edited!

Comment: I think it's more like when `Worker` implements `compareTo(BusinessObject)`, the method should do what it says : comparing to any BusinessObject.

Comment: @kimdung I want the Collections.sort(collection) to always use the comparator of the T class of List<T> collection.

Comment: what if Person.compareTo(Worker) ?

Comment: And rather than `Comparable`, you know that `Collections` can also be sorted with `Comparator` ? That should help you achieve want you want.

Comment: What if the "compareTo" of each sub class is implemented like this? -> `if (!(o instanceof MYTYPE) { return super.compareTo(o) } else { ... use my own implementation}` . Wouldn't this be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is simply not possible to do, what you want to do.
The generic type does and can not have any effect on the methods used from the items.

But you might be able to solve your problem. Just do not use the compareTo methods but instead implement Comparators as needed.

There is a version of Collections.sort() which takes a Comparator as parameter.

Obviously you want to sort the items with different sort criterias depending on the list you are using. So I think the Comparator would be the best solution.

Answer (score 6):

Your design is inherently flawed.

First, you have `BusinessObject` which implements `Comparable<BusinessObject>`. What this says is that business objects have a natural order, dictated by their ID.

Then you override the method in `Person` to compare the name. What you are saying here is that "well, if both business objects being compared are persons, then the natural order is different for them".

That doesn't make sense. Either sorting by ID is natural for business objects, or it isn't. But it can't be natural for some of them, but not for others.

More formally, your override breaks the transitivity requirement of `Comparable`. Imagine you have a list consisting of three business objects: Worker Alice (ID 3), Worker Bob (ID 1), and Company ACME (ID 2). Transitivity says that if `x < y && y < z` then `x < z` must also be true. However, your compare method will give `Bob < ACME` (compare by IDs) and `ACME < Alice` (compare by IDs), but the transitive `Bob < Alice` is false (compare by names). You have violated the requirement documented in the `compareTo` method:

> The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive: (x.compareTo(y)>0 && y.compareTo(z)>0) implies x.compareTo(z)>0.

Bottom line: `Comparable` is not meant to work with open inheritance. Don't do that. Instead, use explicit `Comparator`s for your collections where they make sense.

As a side note, and this may just be due to shortened code in your examples, but you should always override `equals` to be consistent with `compareTo` (i.e. x.equals(y) implies x.compareTo(y) == 0 and vice versa). Anything else means your objects behave in an unintuitive manner. (And then you need to override `hashCode` to fulfill its own contract w.r.t. `equals`. Overriding `equals` but not `hashCode` is a wonderful way to introduce really subtle bugs into Java programs.)

Comment: You're right, I realized it after a few more tests. I'm dropping the implements Comparable<BusinessObject> in BusinessObject, I'll do my sortings using ad hoc Comparator depending on the situation. Thank you for your explanation.